# Launch BottomSheetDialogFragment in UITest

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, dagger-hilt

When I'm trying to write UITests for the app, I've encountered a problem:

- when using espresso to click on the element to launch the BottomSheetDialog fragment, the dialog fragment would just not showing up.
- when explicitly using `launchFragment` to launch the dialog fragment, it would throw an error, because in `Hilt` it requires using `launchFragmentInHiltContainer`.

However, the dialog fragment is a childFragment with a scoped view model, it can't be launched using `launchFragmentInHiltContainer`.

Here's the minimal example of the app:

`FragmentA`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
  private val vm: ViewModelA by viewModels()

  ...
  // in between the lifecycle of onResume() and onStop() the click listener will launch FragmentB
  button.setOnClickListener {
    FragmentB.show(childFragmentManager, "")
  }
}
```

Then `FragmentB` as a dialog fragment, extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentB : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
  private val vm: ViewModelA by viewModels({ requireParentFragment() })
  ...
}
```

`ViewModelA` is a singleton and all its constructors fields are injected using Hilt.

When doing UITest

```
// applied HiltRule
@Test
fun testcaseA() {
  // this would success and I can test everything in FragmentA
  launchFragmentInHiltContainer<FragmentA>()
  
  // then launch the dialog FragmentB
  onView(withId(buttonId))
    .perform(click())
  
  // it appears in RootView, the below will pass
  onView(withText(bottomSheetDialogTitle)).inRoot(isDialog())

  // how should I perform more tests on the elements in Fragment B?
}
```

### What I have tried:

- By using `UIAutomater` to check if the dialog has showed up, and the result is: the dialog did show up, but it is not visible

```
device.wait(
            Until.findObject(
                By.text("Title of the BottomSheetDialog")
            ), 500
        )
```

Also I found this issue: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5158 , but it is reported on Robolectric, seems not related to my problem since I'm not using it.

Stacktrace when trying to launch BottomSheetDialogFragment directly using `launchFragmentInHiltContainer`:

> Fragment is not a child Fragment, it is directly attached to
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper

### Question:

- How to launch a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`(`Fragment B`) from `Fragment A` in Espresso to test against `FragmentB`'s UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `launchFragmentInHiltContainer` as below and launch your dialog fragment (`Fragment B`) individually. Then you can test `Fragment B`'s UI elements.

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    @StyleRes themeResId: Int = R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
    crossinline action: Fragment.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra(
        "androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY",
        themeResId
    )

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
            T::class.java.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs

        if (fragment is DialogFragment){
            fragment.show(activity.supportFragmentManager, "")
        } else {
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
                .commitNow()
        }

        fragment.action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I see that you are using parentFragment's viewmodel in dialog fragment. If you open requireParentFragment() method. You can see the error's root cause.

```
/**
 * Returns the parent Fragment containing this Fragment.
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this Fragment is attached directly to an Activity or
 * other Fragment host.
 * @see #getParentFragment()
 */
@NonNull
public final Fragment requireParentFragment() {
    Fragment parentFragment = getParentFragment();
    if (parentFragment == null) {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " is not attached to"
                    + " any Fragment or host");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " is not a child Fragment, it"
                    + " is directly attached to " + getContext());
        }
    }
    return parentFragment;
}
```

Since you launch the FragmentB directly over HiltTestActivity, so the parentFragment does not exist. For this reason, you need to open the parentFragment first and then open the dialog on it. There is an issue on Github about this topic. The answer has been given clearly. :)

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3181